# Why is clicking too fast giving me a missingReferenceException in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I made a small method that will quickly give the player a "flashlike" display when a sheep is killed. However clicking too fast will trigger a missingReferenceException. Because it registers the raycast a second time. Is this due to the delay on the `DestroyObject()` or something else?

```
private IEnumerator startFlashing(GameObject sheep)
{  
    sheep.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    sheep.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
    sheep.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(theTimeBetweenFlashes);
    sheep.SetActive(true);
    DestroyObject(sheep.gameObject, 0.1f);    
}
```

Comment: I see two potential reasons : 1°) When disabling a gameobject, the `GetComponent` functions will return `null` and/or may produce the error you get. 2°) When calling `DestroyObject`, the components will have a flag "I will be destroyed". But you retrieve them when calling `GetComponent` resulting in the error. You may add a boolean you set to `false` in the `DestroyObject` function, indicating your sheep can't be clicked anymore.

Comment: @Hellium Ye I noticed that it is due to the 2nd iteration incase it gets clicked twice, while "active" . This result in it trying to continue on with data not there. A boolean for this should fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @Hellium that looks fleshed-out enough to serve as an answer that could be Accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the support of @DMGregory, I will post my comment as an answer :

When calling `DestroyObject` (which surely calls [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)), the `sheep` object and its components (rigidbody) will turn to `true` a flag saying "I will be destroyed".

When you retrieve the Rigidbody using `GetComponent`, the function checks this flags and warns you with the message.

I advise you to define a boolean you set to `false` in the `DestroyObject` function indicating your sheep can't be clicked anymore :

```
private bool destroyInProgress = false ;

private IEnumerator startFlashing(GameObject sheep)
{
    if( destroyInProgress ) yield break ;

    sheep.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    sheep.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
    sheep.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(theTimeBetweenFlashes);
    sheep.SetActive(true);
    DestroyObject(sheep.gameObject, 0.1f);
    destroyInProgress = true ;
}
```

Comment: Though it doesn't crash the game any longer I still receiver the Exception. Is something to be ignored or do you recommend a different approach?

Comment: What's the full error? Does it concern the `Rigidbody` component or the gameobject? Does the error point to the `startFlashing` function or an other place in the code?